# C# MVC Edit form not getting some of the values from the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

This might be a dumb question and easily solved but I created 3 new fields on my Edit form, and wanted them to be filled when the page is loaded.

The thing is, this was an application made by people that do not work where i am working anymore (I'm an intern if that is relevant) and the way they passed the data is different from what i've seen on Youtube and other posts here and i cannot seem to figure out why my new data isn't being sent to the form.

The data that is not being sent to the form is the nativeLanguage, secondLanguage and counties

Model

```
public int id_candidate { get; set; }//nao usamos
        public string? candidate_name { get; set; }
        public string code { get; set; } = ""; //nao usas
        public string number { get; set; } 
        public string isActive { get; set; }
        public string availibility { get; set; } = "";
        public string avaMonth { get; set; } = "";
        public string avaYear { get; set; } = "";
        public string birthday_day { get; set; }
        public string birthday_month { get; set; }
        public string birthday_year { get; set; }
        public string notes { get; set; } = ""; //nao usamos
        public string profile { get; set; }
        public string status_candidate { get; set; } = ""; //nao usamos
        public string candidade_notes { get; set; }
        public string desc_processes { get; set; }
        public string timestamp_candidate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); //nao usamos
        public int FK_id_marital_status { get; set; }
        public string status_name { get; set; } = ""; //nao usamos
        public int FK_id_source { get; set; }
        public string source { get; set; } = ""; //nao usamos
        public int FK_id_user { get; set; } = 1;
        public string name { get; set; } = "";  //Table User field name
        public string? FK_id_cat_role_skill { get; set; } //nao usamos
        public string? cat_role_skill_name { get; set; }//nao usamos
        public string? selectedCat { get; set; }
        public string? SelectedRole { get; set; }
        public string? SelectedSkill { get; set; }

        public int FK_candidate_nationality { get; set; } 

        public int? FK_id_actual_location { get; set; } 
        public int FK_id_counties { get; set; }

        public int FK_id_access_candidate { get; set; } 
        public int FK_id_candidate_interest_options { get; set; }
        public string name_candidate_interest_options { get; set; } = "";  //nao usamos
        public string name_candidate_interest_options2 { get; set; } = ""; //nao usamos
        public string country { get; set; } = ""; //nao usamos
        public int FK_id_candidate_processes { get; set; }
        public string? candidateIdentifier { get; set; }
        public string? candidateInterviewer { get; set; }
        public string? nativeLanguage { get; set; }
        public string? secondLanguage { get; set; }

        public string? phone { get; set; }
        public string? email { get; set; }

        public string locality_name { get; set; } = ""; //nao usamos
        public string? salaryExpectation { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<int, string> locations { get; set; } = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        public Dictionary<int, string> Unwantedlocations { get; set; } = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            if (!Session.Exist("id_user"))
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "Login");

            Candidate candidate = new();
            if (id > 0)
            {
                candidate = _candidateService.GetById(id);
                candidate.id_candidate = id;
                Session.Add("id_candidate", candidate.id_candidate);

            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "The id" + id.ToString() + " informated is invalid!";
            }
            return View(candidate);
        }
```

Repository

```
public Candidate GetById(int id)
        {
            string sql = @"SELECT candidate.FK_id_cat_role_skill, candidate.status_candidate, candidate.id_candidate, candidate.code, candidate.candidate_name, candidate.number, native_spoken_language.language_name ,second_spoken_language.language_name, counties.Districts,
                        candidate.availibility, marital_status.status_name, marital_status.marital_acronym, source.source, cat_role_skill.cat_role_skill_name, countries.country, candidate.birthday_day,  
                        candidate.birthday_month, candidate.birthday_year, cities.locality_name, C1.name_candidate_interest_options, 
                        candidate.profile, C2.name_candidate_interest_options AS name_candidate_interest_options2, candidate.desc_processes, candidate.candidade_notes
                        FROM (((((((((((candidate LEFT JOIN candidate_interest_options C1 ON candidate.FK_id_candidate_interest_options = C1.id_candidate_interest_options) 
                        LEFT JOIN marital_status ON candidate.FK_id_marital_status = marital_status.id_status) 
                        LEFT JOIN source ON candidate.FK_id_source = source.id_source) 
                        LEFT JOIN user ON candidate.FK_id_user = user.id_user) 
                        LEFT JOIN cities ON candidate.FK_id_actual_location = cities.id_locality) 
                        LEFT JOIN countries ON candidate.FK_candidate_nationality = countries.id_country)
                        LEFT JOIN candidate_interest_options C2 ON candidate.FK_id_candidate_processes = C2.id_candidate_interest_options)
                        LEFT JOIN cat_role_skill ON candidate.FK_id_cat_role_skill = cat_role_skill.id_cat_role_skill)
                        LEFT JOIN counties ON candidate.FK_id_counties = counties.id_Counties)
                        LEFT JOIN native_spoken_language ON candidate.FK_id_native_language = native_spoken_language.id_native_language)
                        LEFT JOIN second_spoken_language ON candidate.FK_id_second_language = second_spoken_language.id_second_language)
                        WHERE id_candidate = @Id";
            try
            {
                using (IDbConnection dbConnection = _connector.Connectionremanage_2022)
                {
                    return dbConnection.Query<Candidate>(sql, new { Id = id }).FirstOrDefault();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception(e.Message);
            }

        }
```

View

```
 String categoryList = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(selectListCategory);
    String roleList = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(selectListRole);
    String skillList = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(selectListSkill);
    String nativeLanguage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.nativeLanguage);
    String secondaryLanguage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.secondLanguage);
    String Counties = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.FK_id_counties);
    String Source = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.source);
    String maritalStatus = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.status_name);
    String Nationality = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.country);
    String Location = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.locality_name);
    String Options = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.name_candidate_interest_options);
    String Processes = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.name_candidate_interest_options2);

    ViewBag.categoryList = categoryList;
    ViewBag.roleList = roleList;
    ViewBag.skillList = skillList;
    ViewBag.maritalStatus = maritalStatus;
    ViewBag.Source = Source;
    ViewBag.Nationality = Nationality;
    ViewBag.Location = Location;
    ViewBag.Options = Options;
    ViewBag.Processes = Processes;
    ViewBag.ContactCount = candidateContacts.Count;
    ViewBag.Counties = Counties;
    ViewBag.NativeLanguage = nativeLanguage;
    ViewBag.SecondLanguage = secondaryLanguage;


<div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="title">Location(old)</div>
                    @Html.DropDownList("FK_id_actual_location", selectListCity)
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="title">Location</div>
                    @Html.DropDownList("FK_id_counties", selectListCounties)
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="title">Nationality</div>
                    @Html.DropDownList("FK_candidate_nationality", selectListCountry)
                /div>


 <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="title">Native Language</div>
                    @Html.DropDownList("nativeLanguage", selectListNativeLanguage, new { style = "width: 100%;" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="title">Secondary Language</div>
                    @Html.DropDownList("secondLanguage", selectListSecondLanguage, new { style = "width: 100%;" })
                </div>



let categoryList = JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(@ViewBag.categoryList)));
    let roleList = JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(@ViewBag.roleList)));
    let skillList = JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(@ViewBag.skillList)));
    let Source = JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(@ViewBag.Source)));
    let maritalStatus = JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(@ViewBag.maritalStatus)));
    let Nationality = JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(@ViewBag.Nationality)));
    let Location = JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(@ViewBag.Nationality)));
    let Options = JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(@ViewBag.Options)));
    let Processes = JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(@ViewBag.Processes)));
    let secondaryLanguage = JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(@ViewBag.secondaryLanguage)));
    let nativeLanguage = JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(@ViewBag.nativeLanguage)));
    let Counties = JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(@ViewBag.Counties)));


window.onload = function () {

        OnChangeCategory();
        OnChangeRole();
        UpdateStatus("FK_id_marital_status", maritalStatus);
        UpdateStatus("FK_id_source", Source);
        UpdateStatus("FK_candidate_nationality", Nationality);
        UpdateStatus("FK_id_actual_location", Location);
        UpdateStatus("FK_id_candidate_interest_options", Options);
        UpdateStatus("FK_id_candidate_processes", Processes);
        UpdateStatus("FK_id_native_language", nativeLanguage);
        UpdateStatus("FK_id_second_language", secondaryLanguage);
        UpdateStatus("FK_id_counties", Counties);
        OnAvailibilityYearChange();
        document.getElementById("avaYear").addEventListener("change", OnAvailibilityYearChange);

    }
```

What i've tried was adding the variables on the model, adding what was missing on the query located in the repository, adding the viewbags on the view, and trying to update its status on javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I got it, the problem was on the repository, for what I understand the way I am passing data is quite old and it used the fields on the database to map itself on the model, also I wasn't passing the id that would later be used to identify which counties the person was in.

Since I had "Districs" as the variable that would receive the data it was getting the name of the counties which is also wrong, the fix was changing the syntax of the sql string from this

```
counties.Districts
```

to this

```
counties.id_Counties as 'Districts'
```

Allowing the Districts variable on the model to map itself into getting the id from counties.